# Call Controller when third party client call my web-service

Tags: java, web-services, model-view-controller, liferay, portlet

I have web-service exposed at my side and I'm able to get it called when some one hit the URL like

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/XXXXX-Portlets.foo/verify-service \
```

-u test@liferay.com:test \
  -d action=''

Here verifyService(String action) is my method in class now when some one hit this service with curl I'm just taking the example of curl.
You can also call this service like below as well,

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/XXXXX-Portlets.foo/verify-service/action/{valueOfparameter}
```

Now this service hit by third party client and what I want to achieve is when some one call this web service I want to update my jsp with that parameter or want to call my controller.
I am using MVC pattern so its like I have to call my controller class from the my web-service class's method (verifyService).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Controller" means "Portlet" in your case (the Liferay context suggests this) I'd say that your architecture has it wrong. Move the code that you need to call to a service and it'll be natural to call it. Have the portlet as well as the service call the same service with your reusable code.

Consider the portlet world the UI for an application. You wouldn't call UI layer code from your business (or service) layer - whose UI would you call, especially on a webserver where there are potentially huge numbers of concurrent users.

To answer your first comment on this post, I'm not sure what you mean with "CMS endpoint". Liferay's API is available, for historical reasons the CMS interfaces' names start with "Journal", so you can actually create or read articles from your own services by delegating to JournalArticleService etc. This gives you access to the content side, there are also a lot of different APIs for changing/creating pages, adding content to the pages etc. - no need to go through a portlet. All of Liferay's functionality is available through an API. How much you need and which one is probably too much to answer in a single stackoverflow answer - check https://dev.liferay.com for some chapters on accessing Liferay's API. Also, a good starting point is [this blog article (series)](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-)

Comment: yes olaf I know but the third party want CMS endpoint on liferay so that they can push data on our server. I have to expose my service now it is calling my service how would I update my UI layer on service call!!Do we have CMS end point in liferay predefined?

Comment: In their context CMS url is like URL which accept certain command like publish,verify etc and in return liferay provide the json response its success or failure when jobs done.Last question can we have any Content management system on liferay ?

Comment: You should ask another question instead of commenting on an answer to a different question. But the short answer is: "Yes, it just depends on the amount of effort that you're willing to invest". Liferay's CMS comes with zero additional integration effort. Any other CMS will require you to integrate it yourself. Can it be done? Sure. Do I recommend it? It depends - but typically no.